# MySQL can't show table after altering auto_increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I created two tables like this
[image]

and I want to change the added data's id so I use

```
alter table member auto_increment=5;
```

after this, it couldn't show my member table. It shows

```
error 2013: lost connection to MySQL server during query.
```

I thought my table is too big to run, so I changed the limit and the DBMS time out, but it didn't work either. Can someone tell me what's the problem now?

Comment: A) Screenshot is completely worthless and just takes up space. When that is necessary information, *please* use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` which gives output we can actually use to reproduce the problem. A screenshot can't. B) How many rows in this table? C) How active is your server? Is this table being written to? D) Can you create another table and alter it this way, like `CREATE TABLE test LIKE number`?

Comment: If the alter table is doing no change other than setting the `auto_increment`, it doesn't matter how large the table is, because it's a metadata-only change (assuming you use MySQL 5.6 or later). That is, it doesn't copy the table. Are you sure that's the only change you're doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Don't edit your MySQL database when you're connecting it with your Python Flask program. Edit means any CRUD actions.